# Why cant I add to the iterator

Tags: c++, iterator

Why is this compilation error? I basically just want to move the iterator 2 steps forward then modulo it by 3.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    multiset<int> m;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i++)m.insert(i);
    auto it = m.begin();
    it = (it + 2) % 3;
}
```

I can for loop and do it++ and it compiles but when I try to do this it doesn't for some reason.

Comment: Because iterators don't support modulus operations.  They're not numbers.

Comment: Please explain what you expect  `it = (it + 2) % 3;` to do. Maybe that helps to clarify your misunderstanding.

Comment: Wherever you've learned `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`, block that site in your browser, never go there again, and pick up a good C++ book.

Comment: @OP -- What header file is `multiset` declared in?  If you know, then why not `#include` that header, instead of the `bits` header?  If you don't know what header `multiset` is in, then this is the danger of learning C++ code by going to dodgy websites.

Comment: @Yunnosch: Yes! I'm assuming the poster has something at least halfway reasonable that he is trying to do. But I cannot figure it out. Is he trying to get every third element? Out of a `multiset` that only has 2 elements?? In his larger program, does `it = (it + 2) % 3;` appear in a loop somewhere?

Comment: `I can for loop and do it++` -- And so can [std::advance(it, 1);](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/advance).  Maybe `advance` is what you are looking for?

Answer (score 3):

The `std::multiset` iterator is a [*LegacyBidirectionalIterator*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/BidirectionalIterator).

It's required to support pre- and post-increment and decrement operations:

```cpp
--it;
it--;
++it;
it++;
```

It's not required to support `it + n` or the remainder operator.

Answer (score 2):

The error you're encountering is because the arithmetic operations + and % are not directly supported for iterators in C++. This is because the iterator concept is more complex than just a simple index number that can be used in these operations.

Answer (score 0):

The class template `std::multiset` has bidirectional iterators for which the `operator +` is not defined.

And moreover the operator `%` is not defined for all categories of iterators and pointers that also represent iterators.